# Possible to restrict post count in foreach for ghost blogging platform?

Tags: ghost-blog

is it possible to restrict the post count in foreach for example foreach posts=5 ??
thanks in advance.
Ayaz

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the amount of posts shown on each page via your Ghost blog's settings at `<url>/ghost/settings/general/`.

Comment: yes iam aware of that, i am asking for a different way via code/param so i can use it in making of slider/scroller etc.

Comment: It would be nice to retrieve say the most recent 5 posts, or something like that.  Something akin to "take" in LINQ.